# Where is MSDN documentation on OfficeOpenXML.ExcelWorksheet?

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using the EPPlus library and would like to find the documentation for the class OfficeOpenXML.ExcelWorksheet.  I can't seem to get it via Google.

How do I find it?

Comment: Just look into the [source code](https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/0d53d2f885857f6cdf52ef940baae1024e4b301b/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheets.cs#L49).

Comment: EPPlus is an open source project. The [repository](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) has many code examples, but it won't teach you about Open XML. Are you looking for something specific?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is official documentation for EPPlus.

Also, EPPlus is not associated with Microsoft, so it will definitely not be on MSDN. There are a few pages on MSDN about the OfficeOpenXML framework, but not API docs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Comment: That's not just a few pages, that's the entire API reference for Open XML, with a lot of examples in the `How To` section and the entire class library reference